# Are history of engineering/invention questions on topic?

Tags: discussion

For example, a question about the invention of gliders/aircraft by George Cayley, or a question about the development of high pressure steam by Watt et al.

Comment: I recall something about engineering being **off topic** when this site was in definition but that is not a concrete fact.

Comment: I could clarify by posting a couple of questions on the above topics?

Comment: That’s the preferred way to go. This way we can get a much better idea of the issue.

Comment: Will do in the next hour or so...

Answer (score 9):

I would say yes; however, with a caveat - that these clearly demonstrate and focus on an application of scientific and/or mathematical principles for these inventions to work.

Comment: So my examples would be on topic, but "Yet another mouse trap" would not. Seems fair enough.

Comment: Indeed - gliders require knowledge of aerodynamics amongst other things - which is a physics principle being applied